# img сужается в виджете

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Верстаю виджет и возникла проблема, когда уменьшаю окно, рисунок виджета уменьшается, дело все в объеме текста, ширина img фиксированна, сделан блок на флексах.

```css
.widget{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 65px;
  padding-bottom: 65px;
  border: 1px solid @border;
  margin-bottom: 63px;

  &__title{
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 19px;
    letter-spacing:6px;
  }
  
   &__cont{
    padding-left: 61px;
    padding-right: 61px;
    padding-top: 26px;
    width: 100%;
  }

  &__post{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;

  }



  &__img{
    margin-right: 38px;
    max-width: 114px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 65px;
    overflow: hidden;
 

    >a{
      display: block;
    }

    img{
      height: 100%;
    }
  }



  &__posttitle{

    line-height: 20px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing:3px;
  }

  &__posttitle-pos{
    margin-top: -5px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
  }

  &__date{
    color: @tags;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing:3px;
  }


}
```

```html
<div class="widget">
                    <h3 class="title widget__title main-text"><span></span>LATEST POSTS</h3>
                    <div class="widget__cont">
                        <div class="widget__post">
                            <div class="widget__img hidden-xs "><a href=""><img src="/img/wpost1.jpg"
                                                                                         alt=""></a></div>
                            <div class="widget__about">
                                <a href=""><h4 class="widget__posttitle widget__posttitle-pos main-text hover__title">
                                    Living in Los
                                    Angeles </h4></a>
                                <span class="widget__date main-text">OCTOBER 16, 2016</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="widget__cont">
                        <div class="widget__post">
                            <div class="widget__img hidden-xs "><a href=""><img src="/img/wpost2.jpg"
                                                                                         alt=""></a></div>
                            <div class="widget__about">
                                <a href=""><h4 class="widget__posttitle widget__posttitle-pos main-text hover__title">10
                                    LIFE
                                    CHANGING MOMENTS
                                    FROM 10 YEARS AS A NOMAD
                                    around the world </h4></a>
                                <span class="widget__date main-text">OCTOBER 16, 2016</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="widget__cont">
                        <div class="widget__post">
                            <div class="widget__img hidden-xs "><a href=""><img src="/img/wpost3.jpg"
                                                                                         alt=""></a></div>
                            <div class="widget__about">
                                <a href=""><h4 class="widget__posttitle widget__posttitle-pos main-text hover__title">MY
                                    GUIDE TO
                                    ASIAN
                                    FOOD</h4></a>
                                <span class="widget__date main-text">OCTOBER 16, 2016</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы потомок флекс-контейнера не уменьшался, ему необходимо задать свойство `flex-shrink: 0`. В вашем случае, это свойство необходимо добавить блоку `.widget__img`.

Comment: Спасибо большое, Ваша помощь очень мне пригодилась!

Answer (score 1):

У вас же стоит максимальная ширина, а потом относительная. То есть по размеру родительского элемента и строится

```
&__img{max-width: 114px;
    width: 100%;}
```

Надо менять на что-то типа

```
width: 100px;
```